# How to output a static library for iOS project from a Swift package?

Tags: ios, swift, continuous-integration, static-libraries, swift-package-manager

I have a swift package that I want to integrate into my CI and create a static library from it.

This is how the `Package.Swift` looks like:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "CMyLibrary",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v11),
        .watchOS(.v6),
    ],
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "CMyLibrary",
            type: .static,
            targets: ["CMyLibrary"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "CMyLibrary",
            dependencies: ["CWolfCrypt", "CWolfSsl"],
            path: "Sources/CMyLibrary",
            cSettings: [
                .headerSearchPath("./"),
            ]),
        .target(
            name: "CWolfCrypt",
            dependencies: [],
            path: "Sources/CWolfCrypt",
            cSettings: [
                .headerSearchPath("./"),
            ]),
        .target(
            name: "CWolfSsl",
            dependencies: ["CWolfCrypt"],
            path: "Sources/CWolfSsl"),
    ],
    cLanguageStandard: .c11
)
```

Doing a `swift build` command creates a build folder with a static library but it's a static library for MacOS arm64 architecture and can't be integrated into iOS.

How do I specify the architecture for iOS (simulator/device) to create this static library to be used in iOS projects?

Answer (score -1):

```
// Logger.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Logger : NSObject

+(void)log:(NSString *)sLogStr;

@end

// Logger.m

#import “Logger.h”

@implementation Logger

+(void)log:(NSString *)sLogStr{

NSLog(@”%@”,sLogStr);

}

@end
```